# Simple way to bind abstract class model, ASP.Net Core 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, model, abstract

In short, I have a model class which inside of it has some properties as well as some properties which types are abstract classes.

The model looks something like this:

```cs
public class ModelClass
{
    public string SomeProp { get; set; }
    public AbstractOne FirstAbstract { get; set; }
    public AbstractTwo SecondAbstract { get; set; }
}
```

And the abstract classes:

```cs
public abstract class AbstractOne
{
    public virtual Type TwoType { get; set; }
 
    public string SomeProp { get; set; }
    public string SomeOtherProp { get; set; }
}

public abstract class AbstractTwo 
{
    // Its empty
}
```

So in the actual code, I have a class that inherits each one of those abstract classes, and in the controller I initially give the model as:

```cs
return View(new ModelClass() 
{ 
    SomeProp = "Somevalue", 
    AbstractOne = valueUpInTheCode
    AbstractTwo = (AbstractTwo)Activator.CreateInstance(valueUpInTheCode.TwoType)
}
```

Which works fine, the View gets the model, and I can use the html helpers to generate form fields.
I have a form which has a `Html.HiddenFor` for SomeProp and AbstractOne, `DisplayFor` for AbstractOne and `EditorFor` AbstractTwo which is specific to the class that inherits the AbstractTwo, so the `EditorFor` line looks something like this:

> `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.SecondAbstract, Model.SecondAbstract.GetType().Name)`

Which, on the UI seems fine at least, all of the default values or values passed when giving creating model for the view appear and seem to be there.

The problem is when that form is submitted, I have a function that should handle it, for now its empty, but I'm still debugging so I just need some place to put a breakpoint:

```cs
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult Submit(ModelClass model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid == false) return View("Index", model);

    return View("Index", model);
}
```

The problem is, that `model` ends up having all of its properties set how they were entered, but the FirstAbstract and SecondAbstract don't seem to properly bind and end up both being null.

---

So far I've tried some stuff I found on here which seemed to be either outdated or not working for my use case, the closest I got to something working was with this blog on how to make a custom Model Binder:
https://www.palmmedia.de/Blog/2018/5/13/aspnet-core-model-binding-of-abstract-classes

It didn't end up working in the end, but gave me an idea of how something like this should be fixed... And I've got no clue how to do that, or where to start even.